# converting a line of code from c into c++

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int item, jumlahbarang, total = 0, total_belanja = 0, uang, kembalian, sum = 1, memory[100], memory_jumlah[100];
    const char* aitem[11] = { "fillthe0","ITEM 1", "ITEM 2"};
    string repeat;
    int price1= 53000;
    int price2= 76000;

int main(){
    cout << "               | ID   | Nama Barang                     | Harga Barang |" << endl;
    cout << "               |------|---------------------------------|--------------|" << endl;
    cout << "               | 1.   | ITEM 1                          | Rp. 53000    |" << endl;
    cout << "               | 2.   | ITEM 2                          | Rp. 76000    |" << endl;

while (repeat.compare("n") != 0) {
    label:
        cout << " Input item id : ";
        cin >> item;
        memory[sum] = item;
        if (item == 1) {
            cout << " Item anda : " << aitem[1] << endl;
            cout << " How much item do you want ot buy? : ";
            cin >> jumlahbarang;
            memory_jumlah[sum] = jumlahbarang;
            sum++;
            total = price1 * jumlahbarang;
            total_belanja = total_belanja + total;
        }
        else if (item == 2) {
            cout << " Item anda : " << aitem[2] << endl;
            cout << " How much item do you want ot buy? : ";
            cin >> jumlahbarang;
            memory_jumlah[sum] = jumlahbarang;
            sum++;
            total = price2 * jumlahbarang;
            total_belanja = total_belanja + total;
        }

        cout << " Beli Lagi?(y/n)";
        cin >> repeat;
    }

    cout << "\n\n Struk Belanja\n";
    cout << " -------------\n";
    cout << " Item list : \n";
    for (int i = 1; i < sum; i++) {
        printf(" - %dx %s\n", memory_jumlah[i], aitem[memory[i]]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

the code above is a code for making a recipt, the problem i have is i cant convert " `printf(" - %dx %s\n", memory_jumlah[i], aitem[memory[i]]);` " from c languange into c++ , i dont know what code should i use for that. i have tried getline, changing it into cout, it still doesnt work.

from what i know, c++ use cout << instead of printf, ant c++ does not use %d %s.

Comment: `std::cout << " - " << memory_jumlah[i] << ' ' << aitem[memory[i]] <<'\n';`?

Comment: bruh i forgot to input << , i did try this but  only cout << " - " << memory_jumlah[i], aitem[memory[i]] <<'\n'; no wonder it doesnt fkkkin work., thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need that much code to present your issue? Why not just `int memory[100], memory_jumlah[100];
 const char* aitem[11] = { "fillthe0","ITEM 1", "ITEM 2"};
 int main(){ /* Setting values */ printf(" - %dx %s\n", memory_jumlah[3], aitem[memory[3]]); }`? How much more than that do you need to make syntactic sense of that line?

Comment: *"it still doesnt work."* -- this is rather uninformative. Pick the attempt you think is closest to right, show it to us in a [mre], and give us the expected and actual output. (For this, you might need to actually assign values instead of abstracting that away with the comment `/* Setting values */`. Or, skip the variables and hardcode values directly in the `printf` call.)

Comment: noted, thanks for the criticts and advice

Answer (score 2):

Who said that you can't use printf in c++?

C code :

```
printf(" - %dx %s\n", memory_jumlah[i], aitem[memory[i]]);
```

C++ code :

```
printf(" - %dx %s\n", memory_jumlah[i], aitem[memory[i]]);
```

The output would be the same because C++ supports both cout, cin and printf, scanf.

Comment: Well you _can_ use it but stdio.h is a dangerous crap library and should be avoided in C and C++ both... so if C++ gives you a better alternative, use it.

Comment: @Lundin knives can be pretty dangerous, but also very useful. Maybe we should ban knives and printf and languages like C because they could be dangerous. While I agree that `printf` shouldn't be used in C++, I disagree that it shouldn't be used in C; I tend to advocate more for learning how to use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
cout << " - " << memory_jumlah[i] << "x " << aitem[memory[i]] << endl;
```

This should work.

Answer (score -3):

c++ is superset of c so if you are writing any c code then it is a valid c++ code so there is no need to convert in c++
as I compiled your program it is working perfectly fine.

This is the result when I compile this code with extension c++:

[image: 1]

Comment: C++ is not a superset of c. The typical examples are the necessity to cast the result of malloc and the automatic typedef for structs/unions/enums. There are other issues like c++ having additional keywords and lacking some of C99's features.

Comment: It’s nearly a superset of C, in that 98% of C source code will compile as C++, with little or no modification.  Its intent to be a superset of C is how C++ got its name.